# Magento2.3: Product is showing as OUT OF STOCK even the product has set to stock

Tags: product, magento2.3, stock-status, stock-availability

I have created a simple product and set it as IN STOCK and given 1000 in quantity field. However, when I check the product in front-end, I can see the product is showing out of stock.

Why it is showing like that?

Please share your knowledge to rectify this error.

Comment: use php bin/magento indexer:reindex command, flush the cache and try again

Comment: Yes. I have reindexed as well but still I can see the products are displaying as OUT OF STOCK.

Comment: @MagentoDev How did you solved it?